# Получить значение со страницы через расширение

Tags: javascript

Пишу расширение для Chrome, нужно передать переменной **A** значение **document.querySelectorAll('div')**. Проблема заключается в том, что расширение **передает значение html страницы самого расширения**. Как сделать так что бы переменная **A** получала значение страницы **на которой находится пользователь**?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
  var A = document.querySelectorAll('div'); 
  //Какой то код 
});
```

Comment: для этого нужно добавить в расширение *content script*, и передавать ему сообщение c *background page* (используя для этого *Messaging API*). Подробнее - см. в документации разработчика.

Comment: Вот ман: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/messaging 
И вот пример, по смыслу подходящий к вашей задаче: https://gist.github.com/akirattii/2f55bb320f414becbc42bbe56313a28b